# How to chain multiple statements within psycopg2?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I can copy data from a s3 bucket into a redshift table using `psycopg2`:

```
import psycopg2

sql = """ copy table1 from 's3://bucket/myfile.csv'
    access_key_id 'xxxx'
    secret_access_key 'xxx' DELIMITER '\t'
    timeformat 'auto'
    maxerror as 250 GZIP IGNOREHEADER 1 """

cur.execute(sql)
```

How do I string multiple redshift statements to do these three things:

1. create another table (table2) from table1 after data has moved from s3
2. move data over from table1 to table2
3. drop table1

I tried the following:

```
sql = """ copy table1 from 's3://bucket/myfile.csv'
    access_key_id 'xxxx'
    secret_access_key 'xxx' DELIMITER '\t'
    timeformat 'auto'
    maxerror as 250 GZIP IGNOREHEADER 1 
    create table table2 as table1
    drop table table1"""
```

I don't get back any error, but the table is not created, only the copy is working from above. What am I doing wrong in my sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code does `Copy from Table1` to `Table2` by creating a duplicate Copy. Then, it deletes `Table1`.

```
import psycopg2

def redshift():


    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='***', host='******.redshift.amazonaws.com', port='5439', user='****', password='*****')
    cur = conn.cursor();

    cur.execute("create table table2 as select * from table1;")

    cur.execute(" drop table table1;")
    print("Copy executed fine!")




redshift()
```